# Pass formatted text from QML to C++

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qml

I have a simple pdf generator in my QML app, which uses C++ to receive a signal and write my PDF document to the device - when using a sample `TestHtml.html` document in the resources prints as intended, but I'm struggling to be able to send over custom HTML formatted text directly from the QML page.

**What I want to do**

My `reportPage.qml` displays varying data/information, when I click the 'download' button, it sends this formatted data to the C++ to print to PDF, (C++ is *not* my strong point).

**What I have tried**

- Using `QIODevice` to `write` to the .html file, effectively deleting/re-writing the data as needed
- Using QString to pass my text from `reportPage.qml` as a string
- Using QVariant to store my html as an array and pass as this from `reportPage.qml`

My only issue is, where c++ is not my strong point, all I get is errors in my `pdf.cpp` such as undeclared identifiers, no matching member function and so on so fourth

**My Question is**

What is the best way to pass formatted html text using signals/slots form QML to C++ to print as a pdf using my pdf printer shown in the code below?

At Current a simplified part of my code is:

**reportPage.qml**

```
import Felgo 3.0
import com.allbookd.pdf 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Page {
    id: reportPage

    MyPdf {
        id: pdf
    }
    AppButton {
        text: "download"
        var htmlData = "<b>Hello</b> World 
                        <ul>
                            <li>Coffee</li>
                            <li>Tea</li>
                            <li>Milk</li>
                        </ul>"
        onClicked: { pdf.saveInvoice(htmlData); }
    }
}
```

**pdf.h**

```
#ifndef PDF_H
#define PDF_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QPdfWriter>
#include <QDate>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QFile>

class pdf : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit pdf(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void setCurrentDate();
    QString getCurrentDate() const;

signals:

    void invoiceSaved(int error);

public slots:
    QString getPdfPath() const;
    void saveInvoice();

private:
    QString currentDate;
    QString pdfPath;
};

#endif // PDF_H
```

**pdf.cpp**

```
pdf::pdf(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    setCurrentDate();
    QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);
    pdfPath = path + "/invoice_" + getCurrentDate() + ".pdf";
}

void pdf::setCurrentDate()
{
    QDate date(QDate::currentDate());
    int day = date.day();
    int month = date.month();
    int year =  date.year();

    currentDate = QString::number(day) + "_" + QString::number(month) + "_" + QString::number(year);
}

QString pdf::getCurrentDate() const
{
    return currentDate;
}

QString pdf::getPdfPath() const
{
    return pdfPath;
}


void pdf::saveInvoice(QString htmlData)
{
    int error = 0;
    QPdfWriter pdfWriter(getPdfPath());

    pdfWriter.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));

    QPainter painter(&pdfWriter);

    painter.scale(15.0, 15.0);

    QFile file(":/htmlcode.html");    //the HTML file from resources

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        QByteArray temp = file.readAll();   //read it all

        QString html = temp;                //convert it to QString
        QTextDocument doc;
        doc.setHtml(html);                  //set it as HTML

        doc.drawContents(&painter);         

    } else {
        qDebug() << "error: " << file.error();
        error = 1;
    }
    emit invoiceSaved(error);

}
```

Comment: 1) The qresources are read-only so it changes to `if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {` :, also add `painter.end()` after `doc.drawContents(&painter);`

Comment: On the other hand, according to what I understand, you want to send information from QML to C++ but I don't see any code about it.

Comment: Hey @eyllanesc I've just updated my question with some basic html text as an example of what I would be passing over to the printer, you are correct in what you say - I want to send information (formatted text) from QML, to C++.

Comment: I don't see where you use htmlData

Comment: @eyllanesc I have tried passing it through to cpp by declaring in my `pdf.h` and `pdf.cpp` QString htmlData but only error hence left out of the code

Comment: That mistake? Do you have an error message? Have you corrected what I pointed out in the first comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose your **pdf** class to QML. Make functions Q_INVOKABLE to be able to call them directly from QML or even better use Q_PROPERTY

Docs for [Q_INVOKABLE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE)
Docs for [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)

Here is an example:

Register/expose your pdf class to qml in **main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "pdf.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<pdf>("com.allbookd.pdf", 1, 0, "PdfPrinter");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;    
    ............

    return app.exec();
}
```

Make **saveInvoice** function invokable in **pdf.h**:

```
#include <QObject>

class pdf : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit pdf(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void setCurrentDate();
    QString getCurrentDate() const;

    Q_INVOKABLE void saveInvoice(QString htmlData);

    ..............
```

And save *htmlData* to pdf using QPdfWriter:

```
void pdf::saveInvoice(QString htmlData)
{
    int error = 0;
    QPdfWriter pdfWriter(getPdfPath());

    pdfWriter.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));

    QPainter painter(&pdfWriter);
    painter.scale(15.0, 15.0);

    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setHtml(htmlData);
    doc.drawContents(&painter);

    emit invoiceSaved(error);
}
```

Your QML could then look like that:

```
import Felgo 3.0
import com.allbookd.pdf 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Page {
    id: reportPage
    property PdfPrinter pdf: PdfPrinter{}

    AppButton {
        text: "download"
        var htmlData = "<b>Hello</b> World 
                        <ul>
                            <li>Coffee</li>
                            <li>Tea</li>
                            <li>Milk</li>
                        </ul>"
        onClicked: { pdf.saveInvoice(htmlData); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Xplatforms ! It works as intended, initially I received errors on build, but moved the `Q_INVOKABLE void saveInvoice(QString htmlData);` from `public` to my `public slots` and works as intended! Thanks a million